# Angular $animate - delay between ng-enter and ng-leave - not sure why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would be so grateful if someone could take a look at this. It is a very simple angular slide show using angular.enter and angular.leave, but there is a delay between ng-enter and ng-leave that I can't get rid of. At the moment ng-finish has to finish before ng-enter can enter, but I would like the two animations to happen at the same time.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fqJOYxcSR2wO5g7LPQNy?p=preview

JS:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

myApp.controller('sCtrl', function($scope) {$scope.clicks = 0});

myApp.directive('slidesDirective', function ($animate) {
    return  function (scope, element, attr) {

            // Sets up and animates the first slide
            var e1 = angular.element('<div class="slide"><br>Odd Slide<p>Click Me</p></div>');
            var e2 = angular.element('<div class="slide"><br>Even Slide<p>Click Me</p></div>');

            $animate.enter(e1, element);

            // Checks if the click counter value has changed. 
            scope.$watch('clicks', function(val) {

              if (val) {

                 if (val % 2 === 0) {

                   $animate.leave(e2);
                   $animate.enter(e1, element);

                  } else {
                    $animate.leave(e1)
                    $animate.enter(e2, element);

                   }
              }
            })
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="clicks = clicks + 1" class="slides" slides-directive></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the animation CSS a bit to achieve what I think you're asking for. I made one of the DIVs green to illustrate the animation.

http://plnkr.co/edit/MED5NRJLiBfEaeuCNl3L?p=preview

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking for, except that the site is destined for mobile devices, and I am hoping to use hardware accelerated transforms to make the animation look smooth. Any ideas how I could do that? I have tried translate3D(100%, 0,0) - but it didn't seem to work very well in some browsers... where as translateX seems to be quite well supported.

Comment: I just had a look at your solution in the IOS Simulator, and it isn't displaying correctly for some reason. I think the answer might lie with getting the two animations to occur at the same time.

Comment: I just updated the plnkr to use translateX instead of the left:0. Hopefully that'll help. Note that I left out a bunch of browser prefixes since I'm just using Chrome - so you should add those back in.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Update the plunkr with those prefixes - http://plnkr.co/edit/VRpDblnWiOy6PzY15UNc?p=preview - Just tried it on a rake of modern browsers. All worked very well except for firefox. Not sure if there is a trick to that one?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working - I'm not sure why Firefox would have any issues. At least iOS and Chrome work so that should cover the majority of your mobile users.